# How to skip first row of data from csv in BASH

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=","
home=( $(cut -d ',' -f2 Home.csv ) )
printf "%s\n" "${home[*]}"
```

This stores the column name as first element of array. How to I avoid column name i.e first row

Comment: `array=( $(...anything...) )` is an antipattern; don't do it in the first place.

Comment: ...see [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) expounding on the above, or for a concrete example of where it goes wrong, try reading an input file where one of the users has a `home` value of `*`.

Comment: Also, because your `IFS` is `,`, you're storing **all** your home directories in only the very first element of the array! You just can't tell that when you use `printf '%s\n' "${array[*]}"` to test its value, because the output doesn't distinguish between a newline inside the data and one added by the `printf` format string.

Comment: ...try comparing that with `printf '<%s>\n' "${array[@]}"`, which will have lines like `<home1>`, `<home2>`, etc. when your array is correctly-formed.

Comment: (Another way to unambiguously print a variable's value in bash is to use `declare -p home`, which will print something like `declare -a home=( [0]="first value" [1]="second value" [2]="third value" )` if you have a 3-element array).

Answer (score 1):

Before we go into answering your literal question, note that it's easy to offset your output when you expand the array, or just delete an item from the array by number. Thus:

```
readarray -t home < <(cut -d, -f2 Home.csv)  # read each line into an array element
unset 'home[0]'                              # remove the first array element
printf '%s\n' "${home[@]}"                   # print the array's contents
```

...or...

```
readarray -t home < <(cut -d, -f2 Home.csv)  # read each line into an array element
printf '%s\n' "${home[@]:1}"  # print the array's contents, skipping the 1st element
```

---

One easy way to fix this is to consume your header before you start reading the body content. If you have bash 4.0 or newer, and thus the `readarray` builtin:

```
{ read _; readarray -t home; } < <(cut -d2 -f2 Home.csv)
```

By the way -- you don't need `cut` for this at all. Consider:

```
homes=( )                          # initialize an empty array
{                                  # start a code block (for our redirection below)
  read _                           # read the first line of input and throw it out
  while IFS=, read -r _ home _; do # loop over following lines, split on commas,
    homes+=( "$home" )             # ...adding the 2nd column to our array...
  done
} <Home.csv                        # ...with everything in the block reading from Home.csv
```

The point of `IFS=, read -r _ home _` is to put the first column into a throwaway variable named `_`, the second column into `home`, and everything else in the line also into a throwaway `_` variable. For more on this, see [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).